# How to define a name of a callback function properly as argument, if the callback name is defined in other class

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

This is a bit of a mock-up: I have test class and columnHeader class. The test class calls a function with a loop through all the table columns on the table. For each column, I would like to apply either filtering or a sorting.
With the following code my problem is, that eslint complains:

> let columnHeader:
>  ColumnHeader Avoid referencing unbound methods which
> may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.

and even more the variable tableNam is not defined in the callback functions (clickColumnActionFilter,clickColumnSort).

The test file:
import { ColumnHeader } from '../../../support/spa/ColumnHeader';

```
export function tableColumnActionTest() {
  describe(`Table column sorting and filtering`, () => {
    let columnHeader = new ColumnHeader();

    before(() => {
      A_page.visit(//some url);
      columnHeader = new ColumnHeader();
      columnHeader.setTableN('aTable');
    });

    it.only('Select column action tests', () => {
      columnHeader.loopThroughColumnHeader(columnHeader.clickColumnActionFilter);
    });
  });
}
```

The class file:

```
import { table } from './Table';

interface Action {
  (colId: string): void;
}

export class ColumnHeader {
  tableNam: string;

  setTableN(tabN: string) {
    this.tableNam = tabN;
  }  

  clickColumnSort(colName: string) {
    cy.log(`tableName: ${this.tableNam}`);
    // do sorting
  }

  clickColumnActionFilter(colName: string) {
    cy.log(`tableName: ${this.tableNam}`);
    // do filtering
  }

  loopThroughColumnHeader(columnAction: Action): void {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        table.getColumnIdFromNr(i);
        cy.get('@COLID').then(($colIDent) => {
          const colId = $colIDent as unknown as string;
          columnAction(colId);
        });
        cy.wait(500);
      }
    });
    table.getColumnNameFromNr(2);
  }
}

export const columnHeader = new ColumnHeader();
```

Do you know how to call the function name as argument properly so that the environment is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out:
In the test file, I needed to bind the columnheader.
This solved the eslint complaint and the undefined member variable

```
columnHeader.loopThroughColumnHeader(columnHeader.clickColumnActionFilter.bind(columnHeader));
```

instead of just:

```
columnHeader.loopThroughColumnHeader(columnHeader.clickColumnActionFilter)
```